# Ubuntu 22.04 taking 3 minutes to load kernel

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04

After upgrading from 20.04, the boot process now takes minutes more than before.

I'm using kernel `5.19.0-051900rc6-generic` and Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Log from `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 4.675s (firmware) + 3.850s (loader) + 3min 2.684s (kernel) + 13.403s (userspace) = 3min 24.613s 
graphical.target reached after 13.348s in userspace
```

Link to the 'before splash' screen:
[image]

Part of `dmesg` (can't understand the gap):

```
[    2.459444] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
[    2.523058] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
[  182.627404] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[  182.703718] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[  182.725742] systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.9 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
[  182.725807] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[  182.726101] systemd[1]: Hostname set to <grey15>.
```

I already tried to uncomment these lines in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` while altering the timeouts to like 10s, but nothing changed:

```
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
```

Another issue I had these days is that linker can't find `-lpangox-1.0`, when building a c++ application using flycapture and ogre. So it may be related to some sort of graphics issue. (obs. the lib is actually already installed)

Edit: Solved after doing a fresh-install...